# UPDATE de acuerdo a select

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT
      t1.Descripcion,
      t1.IdReg,
      t2.IdReg As IdRegSegIncidente 
FROM 
     INCIDENTES t1
JOIN 
     (SELECT 
             IdRegIncidente,
             MAX(IdReg) IdReg 
      FROM 
             SEGUIMIENTO_INCIDENTES 
      GROUP BY 
             IdRegIncidente) t2
ON 
      t1.IdReg = t2.IdRegIncidente
```

La consulta anterior me devuelve la siguiente tabla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo utilizar la consulta anterior para hacer un update a la tabla `SEGUIMIENTO_INCIDENTES` usando el campo `IdRegSegIncidente`?

Comment: Podrias explicar que datos quieres actualizar y que estructura tienen las dos tablas?

Comment: La primer tabla INCIDENTES: IdReg | Descripcion 
La segunda tabla SEGUIMIENTO_INCIDENTES contiene : IdReg | IdRegIncidente | Estatus

La relación es IdReg (Primary Key) de la tabla INCIDENTES con IdRegIncidente (Foreign Key) de la tabla SEGUIMIENTO_INCIDENTES

y el campo que quiero actualizar es Estatus el cual es varchar

no incluyo todos los campos de las tablas porque no los considero necesario para este caso

Comment: El código relevante, añádelo editando la pregunta con el enlace editar que sale bajo ella.

Answer (score 0):

Así:

```
Update SEGUIMIENTO_INCIDENTES 
set SEGUIMIENTO_INCIDENTES.ColumnaActualizar = Valor
FROM 
     INCIDENTES t1
JOIN 
     (SELECT 
             IdRegIncidente,
             MAX(IdReg) IdReg 
      FROM 
             SEGUIMIENTO_INCIDENTES 
      GROUP BY 
             IdRegIncidente) t2
ON 
      t1.IdReg = t2.IdRegIncidente
```